# fastCGi with Django: "missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!"

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi

I'm under Apache + fastCGI with Django 1.8

My folder on the shared host looks like:

`/home/username/`

`/home/username/MyProject_SRC`

`/home/username/MyProject_SRC/MyProject/manage.py`

and:

`/home/username/public_html/.htaccess`

`/home/username/public_html/index.fcgi`

I've edited `.htaccess` and `index.fcgi` to look like this:

**.htaccess :**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.fcgi
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**index.fcgi:**

```
#!/home/username/djangoenv/bin/python3
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/username/MyProject_SRC")

os.chdir("/home/username/MyProject_SRC")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "MyProject.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Now, when I do on the server:

```
(djangoenv)username@hostname [~/public_html]# ./index.fcgi 
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
.... // Normal webpage
</html>
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
```

Going on my Home webpage returns a `500 internal error` without more in the logs.

**EDIT** I've got the same result when doing:
`(djangoenv)username@hostname [~/MyProject_SRC]# ./manage.py runfcgi`

Comment: I don't understand what you are hoping to achieve by running index.fcgi in your shell. It's supposed to be called by Apache when you request a page.

Comment: Okay, I've edited with `./manage.py runfcgi`. Basically I'm only trying to know where the problem is since I've only got a 500 internal error without anything. Is there another test to know whether fastCGI is working correctly with my Django config?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, in my case I did not find a specific source, but I tried to add this in my **index.fcgi** and doing ./index.fcgi no longer asked me, if it keeps getting 500 check the version of **flup** you are using, which be **1.0.2** preferably.

```
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "GET"
os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = "yourdomain.com"
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = "80"
os.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = "HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, the problem turned out to be that a server change had removed all of my custom installed python packages, including `flup`. So the fix was simply to install it:

```
pip3 install flup
```